# How to exclude results in Mysql query when using RAND()

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query

```
"SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5"
```

but i dont want to display data with ID =3

from this table... is that possible with `rand()` function ?

EXAMPLE: I have 10 images in table with `id=1` `id=2` and `id=3` `id=4` `id=5`.... now i want to display all images random except image with `id=3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just add a `WHERE` statement (and remove `LIMIT`, since you want *all* images):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `TABLE`
WHERE
    `ID` != 3
ORDER BY
    RAND()
```

Comment: hmm u dont understand me..i have table with images and every image have id  and i want to display all images from that table with random() function but without image with id=3 ...

Comment: @John, if you want to display *all* images, then do not use `LIMIT 5`. I've changed my answer.